# Anonymous coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, anonymous-function, coroutine, yield-return

First of all this is what I want to do:

```
delegate IEnumerator EnemySpawningRoutine();

EnemySpawningRoutine[] enemySpawners = new EnemySpawningRoutine[] {
    () => {
        //variables
        //spawn
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        //complex stuff
        //more spawning
    },
    () => {
        //same as above
    }
};

IEnumerator EnemySpawningRoutine() {
    IEnumerator currentSpawnRoutine;
    while(isGameRunning) {
        currentSpawnRoutine = //choose one of enemySpawners
        StartCoroutine(currentSpawnRoutine);
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => {
            //return true if all enemies are dead or something like that.
        });
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems like this is impossible, because the yield return functionality is not supported in delegates or anonymous functions.

Is there another way to achieve the same effect as above without anonymous IEnumerators?

Comment: @HimBromBeere it's Unity3D's old way of executing a "task" over a series of frames

Comment: You could define a [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) in the same scope as the rest of your code and place them in `enemySpawners`. Local functions will allow yielding. Will Unity allow local functions (C# >= 7.0) though?

Comment: Don't use Unity3D's coroutines as they are obsolete and not to mention a bad c# practice.  Use `Task` now that Unity3D supports it

Comment: @MickyD I'm using unity 2018, which doesnt support Tasks anymore. And why are coroutines bad practise?

Comment: @MickyD Coroutines and Tasks are completely different things. Coroutines are not obsolete, deprecated, or in any other way "discouraged."

Comment: @T.Grumser I think it is called `JobHandle` in Unity. I messed around with it for a few minutes before deciding that it couldn't do what I wanted.

Comment: Ah, found it. `IJob`, the handle is a related object, but IJob is the interface that represents the task.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you like this:

```
public IEnumerator Co_Test(params Action[] actions)
{
    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
            action();
    }

    yield return actions;
}
```

and use like this:

```
StartCoroutine(Co_Test(() =>
    {
        //first function
    }, () =>
    {
        //socond
    }, /*and as much as you want*/));
```

beside you can use "Wait" functions like this:

```
public IEnumerator Co_Test(Func<bool> b, params Action[] actions)
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(b);
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            action();
        }
    yield return actions;
}
```

and use it:

```
StartCoroutine(Co_Test(new Func<bool>(() =>
        {
            if (Enemies.isAllDead) return true;
            else return false;
            
        })
    ,() =>
    {
        //it wait until the above Func return true;

    }));
```